# How to prevent CSS transform skew from breaking child element position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider this navbar here working perfect. When you hover over the dropdown a full width dropdown menu shows:

http://www.bootply.com/MhEn027pSZ

Now I want to add a skew for visual reasons to the li parent element on the navbar, but it messes up the dropdown menu and causes it to not be full width:

http://www.bootply.com/N79PbLKa1W

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening and how to fix it

Comment: Do you need it to look like this?: http://www.bootply.com/tA5DAHJjv9

Comment: oh wow easy enough. Yes that's what I needed. So I just need to apply the skew to the `a` element instead. If you wouldn't mind posting it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need apply a skew for `<a>` inside an `<ul>`, not for `ul`:

```
.has-dropdown a {
    position: relative !important;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
  }
```

Comment: one last question, how could I keep the text straight but the element skewed? So when I apply a background color it looks skewed, but the text is not?

Answer (score 2):

`.has-dropdown` contains both the menu title and the menu's items so applying `skew` to `.has-dropdown` effects both.

Instead, apply `skew` to only the menu title:

```
.has-dropdown > a {
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}
```